# Solve black screen while converting textview into bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, textview, screenshot

I want to convert textView into Bitmap but I am getting blackscreen Instead of the data inside textview.

Screen I want to convert

[image]

Screen which I am getting after drawing cache

[image]

I don't know where I am going wrong.

Following is my code

**abc.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="3"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.bgc.activity.AlterQuotes"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_alter_quotes">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/AlterQuotesrl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.18">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AlterQuotestvTestText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/frame"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/sample_name"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**abc.java**

```
RelativeLayout z = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.AlterQuotesrl);
z.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
z.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmapSetDrawingChache = Bitmap.createBitmap(z.getDrawingCache());
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapSetDrawingChache.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

// saving in sdcard
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "Birthday Card" + File.separator);
if(!file.exists())
    file.mkdirs();

String imageName = "Image-" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ".jpg";

fileImagePath = new File(file,imageName);
try {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileImagePath);
    fileOutputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
    fileOutputStream.close();

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlterQuotes.this);
    adb.setTitle("Alert");
    adb.setMessage("You will not be able to change, are you sure you want to continue?");
    adb.setIcon(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_black_alert_two));
    adb.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(AlterQuotes.this, CardMaker.class);
            intent.putExtra("bitmapPath",fileImagePath.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    adb.show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: i think ur background frame is transparent, try putting background color to like white then try

Comment: @Anders it worked thanks man. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transparent background usually causes the background to get black when converted into bitmap, try putting background color of your background frame of `TextView` to somewhat like white color then try converting it to bitmap.

Comment: Small but very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating bitmap from TextView, currently you are converting RelativeLayout to Bitmap...