# Android screenshot of custom view results in black image

Tags: android

I have a class CameraSourcePreview, which extends ViewGroup.

```
public class CameraSourcePreview extends ViewGroup
```

This custom view is used in following XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/photo_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.55">

        <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay
                android:id="@+id/face_overlay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I'm trying to do, is to make a screenshot of LinearLayout:

```
 View photoLayout = (View) findViewById(R.id.photo_layout);
                    photoLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    photoLayout.buildDrawingCache(true);

 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(photoLayout.getDrawingCache());
                    photoLayout.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
                    photoLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                    try {
                        File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile(), "snap.png");
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                        Log.d(Values.CAMERA_TAG, "Saved picture to" + myFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

The problem is: Screenshot is saved, however, CameraSourcePreview view is always black. GraphicOverlay is captured fine.

To note: CameraSourcePreview is a realtime camera view. GraphicOverlay draws a picture over the person's face (when detected).

Comment: Refer my post: [Solve black screen while converting TextView into bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38850809/4629101). Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Pankaj, thanks for your reply! Fortunately, in your case it was a solution since you had a black View with transparent background, which caused a problem. In my case, I don't need a background, because live CameraSourcePreview should display full camera view...